# How to load a UTF-8 text file with InputStream

Tags: java, android, utf-8, io, inputstream

I want to load a .txt file from my assets folder into a text view by pressing a button. I did this so but my problem is that my text file is UTF-8 Encoded text and some strange characters are copied into my TextView instead my true words...
Here is my code and method I wrote but I don't know where I should put "UTF-8" as an argument..

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                
            try {
                InputStream iFile = getAssets().open("mytext.txt");
                String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
                Intent intent=new Intent(MyActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("myExtra", strFile);
                final int result=1;
                   startActivityForResult(intent, result);
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

public String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(is);
    String strLine = null;
    while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
        sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
    }
    dataIO.close();
    is.close();
    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: **1** - Put the UTF-8 definition in the xml layout. **2** - use a **font** which has all the glyphs for that specific language. **3** - save the text file as Unicode UTF-8 encoding (it won't be translated by the Android side). That is, `don't use Windows Notepad` to save the file.

Comment: Try to add an extra argument to open() or new().

Comment: `InputStreamReader` has an overload for charsets, use that one instead of a regular `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code reads your file into byte array buffer and converts it to string

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    int bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8");
}
```